# Magento Cannot products to related,upsell,crossell. showing error

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`cl55-m755`.`catalog_product_link`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNK_TYPE_ID_CAT_PRD_LNK_TYPE_LNK_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`link_type_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_link_type`
>   (`link_type_id`) ON),

query was:

`INSERT INTO`catalog_product_link`(`product_id`,`linked_product_id`,`link_type_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

While selecting products for related/upsell/crossell shows this error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_type` (`link_type_id`, `code`)
>   VALUES (1, 'relation'), (3, 'super'), (4, 'up_sell'), (5,
>   'cross_sell');

This solved the issue.